# Calculating the standard deviation from columns of values and frequencies in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, standard-deviation, frequency-distribution

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of a set of values in PowerBI and I am stuck. There are two columns in a table (days and count).  This is a frequency distribution of a transportation lane. Days goes from 1 to 100, count is the number of shipments that took those number of days.

The formula to calculate the standard deviation of a frequency distribution is pretty straight forward: sqrt(sum(fx * (x - avgx)^2))/sum(fx))  But the Dax is giving me a massive headache.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: can you please add some code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the example from the [Standard deviation Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples) as sample data.

[image: wiki data]

Converted to Power BI equivalent and fit your requirement as days and count:

[image: power bi data]

And the measure is created as follows, the tricky part is to make use of the [SUMX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634959.aspx) function. I deliberately break down the intermediate steps with `VAR` to make it more clear.

```
st_dev = 
VAR x_sum = SUMX(Lane, Lane[Days] * Lane[Count])
VAR x_count = SUM(Lane[Count])
VAR mean = x_sum / x_count
VAR dev_sq_sum = SUMX(Lane, POWER(Lane[Days] - mean, 2) * Lane[Count])
RETURN SQRT(dev_sq_sum / x_count)
```

Result:

[image: result]

P.S. Power BI actually has some built-in functions for calculating standard deviation, e.g. [STDEVX.P](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492208.aspx), but it's not that useful in this case. Feel free to check it out though.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This works like a charm.  And wonderful job explaining the answer!